# Pivoting Text File Into Excel

Tags: pandas

I have a text file from an outside vendor that looks like this:

```
DOS     :5/22/1980
SERVICE :Pruning
COST    :$34.00
DOS     :4/2/1980
SERVICE :Mowing
COST    :$8.88
```

I need to bring this into Excel with 3 columns: `DOS,SERVICE,COST`.

Under each column, it shows the appropriate value:

```
DOS         SERVICE     COST
5/22/1980   Pruning     $34.00
4/2/1980    Mowing      $8.88
```

The colon is always in the same position.

Comment: Based on your tag, you seem to use ```pandas```. Could you please share what have you tried in this regard so far?

Comment: Looks like a typical PowerQuery task in Excel.

Comment: Phyast10: yes, I will post my code shortly.

Comment: Peter - I am using Python as this will become an automated task. Once the Excel file is created, it will be emailed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from io import StringIO

txtfile = StringIO("""DOS     :5/22/1980
SERVICE :Pruning
COST    :$34.00
DOS     :4/2/1980
SERVICE :Mowing
COST    :$8.88""")

df = pd.read_csv(txtfile, header=None)

df1 = df[0].str.split('\s:', expand=True).set_index([0])

df_ex = df1.set_index(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)[1].unstack(0)
df_ex.to_excel('out.xlsx', index=False)
```

Output:

[image]